# Xcode debugger not showing values for variables?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, swift4.2, xcode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my iOS Application, while execution stops at break point, variables at that scope not showing values.

I tried cleaning build, deleting derived-data and also optimization level to none, but nothing helped.

I am using Xcode version 10.1 and Swift 4.2.

[Screenshot of debug area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCywX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, in debugger `e myVariable` or `p myVariable`